# Bottom sheet go out of screen when dragging very fast in Android

Tags: android, material-components-android, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, material3

I am a strange situation. I have made a standard bottom sheet in my app. Everything works fine until I start dragging to close the bottom sheet in a speedy way. The bottom sheet seems go out off screen (you can check the attached gif below). I have checked its slide-offset and the slide-offset reached negative float in this case. Any ideas to keep the bottom sheet not go out of screen?

[image]

**Update**: This is my layout structure and bottom sheet config for double checking if necessary.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/standard_bottom_sheet" app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
            // Bottom sheet content
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Material lib version **1.9.0**

App theme is extended from `Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar`

Init bottom sheet like this: `BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.standardBottomSheet)`

Comment: I would double check if all of this configured properly. If it is I would open issue in ```BottomSheet``` repository and either submit PR which fix issue or take a code to customize it to use it locally with the patch.

Comment: @Gleichmut Yeah. If you don't mind, please let me know if your find a solution for this case. Thanks